# Docker /bin/sh took 10 second to stop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to make a docker container running as daemon for developing my Go program and mount source code into it using `volume`. So any `go` tools run inside the container. I'm running the container using docker-compose with `tty: true`, `stdin_open: true`, and override `entrypoint: /bin/sh`.

Everything is worked well except it took 10 second to stop the container. After some search, the problem caused by `/bin/sh`, it's runs as PID 1 and doesn't handle `SIGTERM` properly. I found tools like [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) and [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) that runs as PID 1.

Now my Dockerfile contain

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

I think I miss something because it's still took 10 second to stop the container. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How do you stop the container? Typing Ctrl-D in the shell would stop the shell immediately.

Comment: I'm running container using `docker-compose up -d` and enter container using `docker-compose exec <service> sh`, yes Ctrl-D will exit the shell but container still running. I stop the container using `docker-compose stop`.

Comment: Actually it's not a big problem since changing `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` is not that frequent, thus invoking `docker-compose up -d` is only few times and my day to day command is `go` tools inside the container.

Comment: So you are actually running two shells in the container, one started when the container starts and a second one when you exec into it.

Comment: I don't know, but form my understanding, fired up `docker-compose` doesn't give you shell in the container, only after exec into it I get the shell. So I think it's only 1 shell.

Comment: You should just [install Go](https://golang.org/doc/install) normally.  It's much easier to just type `go` than `sudo docker run -v... -u $(id -u) golang go`, and there aren't really any benefits from trying to use Docker this way.  The `$GOROOT` and `$GOPATH` environment variables give isolation between Go installations and projects, if that's your goal.

Comment: @DavidMaze of course if I'm only develop Go, i'm not bother using docker. If u can see, I'm using docker-compose because well I'm invoking another service in another language.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your own `entry-point` script that can handle all `signals` and pass to child processes inside container. That way you can gracefully stop your services and moreover take care of `zombie` processes as containers shutdown unexpectedly.
https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/